# Is it possible to inject JavaScript that reads 'strings'?

Tags: javascript, code-injection

I've heard of 'injecting' JavaScript, but I'm not fully sure on what it does, or how you do it. But I'm wondering if you can inject it into a site in order to read the 'strings' or 'forms'?

For example: Say there's a site that has a field for entering a name. Is there a way to inject JavaScript to make it fill the field with 'James' each time it finds a field requiring a name?

Or would there be a better way to do this?

Comment: are you trying to do a keylogger?

Comment: or an automatic form filler? There are browser plugins for that.

Comment: Sorta like an automatic form filler for job applications.

Answer (score 1):

I use this function for userscripts

```
function ex(function_contents){
    var exec_script = document.createElement('script');
    exec_script.type = 'text/javascript';
    exec_script.textContent = "(" + function_contents.toString() + ")()";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(exec_script);
}
```

called with

```
ex(function(){
    document.write("HELLO!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

seems you are looking for [content_script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) or [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)

Comment: aka Greasemonkey, aka user-script.